# openpyxl - Changing the scatterStyle of a chart to 'marker'

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl, scatter

I use openpyxl to create scatterCharts in an .xlsx-file.
The default style of the chart is "line". I want to change this style to "marker".
http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/charts/scatter.html
says, that it is the best way to do this by changing the style of the series.
I tried different things:

1st:

```
chart = openpyxl.chart.ScatterChart(scatterStyle='marker')
```

--> no Effect

2nd:

```
chart.scatterStyle = "marker"
```

--> no Effect, maby i have to place this line on a special place?

3rd:

```
series = openpyxl.chart.Series(yvalues, xvalues, title_from_data=True)
series.marker=openpyxl.chart.marker.Marker('x')
```

--> now i have lines with markers, so it seems, that i am on the right way. But i have not found a way to remove the lines.

Comment: The only documentation for this is the OOXML specification and an understanding of the default rendering styles of applications like Micrsoft Excel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
series.marker=openpyxl.chart.marker.Marker('x')
series.graphicalProperties.line.noFill=True
```

will add markers to the graph and remove the lines.

Additional information:

to find properties and methods of the objects like "series" you can use

```
dir(series)
```

to show all properties and methods of this object. There you find the "graphicalProperties"

and with

```
dir(series.graphicalProperties)
```

you can find "line" ... and so on

Comment: fyi if you want random markers just use ```openpyxl.chart.marker.Marker("auto")```